# How much grain can a giant node produce with the production per 25 perk?

Tags: against-the-storm

The total amount of stuff from a node can be increased by getting perks. Here are two such perks;

**Mold supply**: Increase the production of grain by +1 (or +2)

**Grain harvest**: Increase the production of grain by +1 for every 25 grain harvested.

For a single small (15) or big (60) node of grain, +2 production beats out +1 per 25 harvested, as the node is mostly empty before it kicks in.

The marshlands though have giant nodes (1,000). It's pretty easy to see that the +1 grain production for every 25 harvested will get you more grain. I was just wondering how much more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cornerstone is in fact like this:

`Grain production increases by +1 every 25 times it's produced.`

That is to say, you get +1 for every 25 *times* harvested, not for every 25 *grains* harvested. So the answer by aphid is correct given the question, but it does not correspond to the game mechanic.

Some javascript to simulate:

```
let gTotal = 0
let harvestAmount = 1
let harvestTimes = 0

while (harvestTimes < 1007) {
  harvestTimes++
  gTotal = gTotal + harvestAmount
  harvestAmount = Math.floor(1 + harvestTimes / 25)
  console.log(`harvestTimes: ${harvestTimes}, totalHarvested: ${gTotal}`)
}
```

And you end up with 20787 harvested grains.

Comment: It must have been changed at some point. I retested it and this is how it works now.

Comment: @aphid At no point have I seen it work the way you describe and I've been playing the game since December.

Answer (score 2):

**20787**

I was notified that the cornerstone actually works differently: based on harvest count, not total harvested.

This simplifies the math. I'd like to add another way of calculating the true answer, using some simple high school maths that doesn't require any programming.

The question is to sum 1, 1, 1 (25 times) , 2, 2, 2 (25 times) , ... (until 1007 numbers are summed).

First, re-arrange the first 1000 numbers into the sequence `v40 = 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 40` repeated 25 times.

Use the formula for arithmetic sum:

```
Sn = 0.5n (n + 1)
```

To get:

```
Vn = 25 * Sn
V40 = 20 * 25 * 41 = 20500
```

Finally, our answer `W = V40 + 7 * 41 = 20500 + 287 = 20787`

---- Original answer below for context ----

**2,057,467,409,163,578,097 Grain**

More than you might expect, as it scales exponentially. Basically; the node is for all intents and purposes now infinitely big.

This is assuming you have all the unlocks. (1,007 charges instead of 1,000) . With 1,000 you can get 'only' 1,563,506,134,306,101,294.

This also doesn't factor in double production chance. If you have that, the number will obviously vary.

This cannot be computed exactly with a spreadsheet, you need bignums. Python has this builtin, so this should print the result as the final output line:

```
#!/bin/python


gTotal = 0;
harvestAmt = 1;
slots = 1007;

while(slots > 0): 
    slots = slots - 1;
    gTotal = gTotal + harvestAmt;
    harvestAmt = 1 + gTotal // 25;
    print("%s : %s" % (slots, gTotal));
```