# Does getting bonus/chance resources from a node count as "producing" them?

Tags: against-the-storm

Consider the cornerstone Fungal Guide, "Mushroom production increases by +1 every 25 times it's produced". In the Marshlands biome, Mushwood trees have a 15% chance to give mushrooms when a woodcutter harvests them. Do the mushrooms that come from these trees count as having been "produced" and thus count towards improving mushroom production? Or are they some sort of extra and only the primary yield of the tree, wood, counts as having been produced?

Comment: related question: [How much grain can a giant node produce with the production per 25 perk?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/401170/how-much-grain-can-a-giant-node-produce-with-the-production-per-25-perk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes

Finally had this combination come up again today, and since you live multiple times (in video games), I risked wasting a cornerstone pick and chose it. Over the course of the game I racked up +4 to mushroom production from that cornerstone, so I can confirm that it works and "bonus" resources are considered to have been "produced".